# OLE automation WordBasic macro for signing document

Tags: vba, ms-word, ole, wordbasic

I am looking for a way how to sign a Word document using OLE automation.

Is there a macro of WordBasic object which I could use?

Something like Signatures.Add  in VBA.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Wow, you're really still using WordBasic?

Comment: You can easily move forward to a newer version and keep your old code:
"In Word 2000 and later, when you open a Word version 6.0 or Word for Windows 95 template that contains WordBasic macros, the macros are automatically converted to Visual Basic modules. Each WordBasic statement and function in the macro is converted to the corresponding WordBasic method."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Application.WordBasic

Comment: Is there a reason for not using vba? Are you running Word  6.0 applications?

Comment: There is a reason. Word is not fully automated application. It has just one object which can be used in OLE Automation and that is WordBasic, as far as I know.